Error in opening the text file in python from the other directory
The code is
case 'show' | 'display':
      file = open('files/todos.txt','r')
      todos = file.readlines()
      file.close()
      for i,j in enumerate(todos):
          #print(i,"-",j)
          j = j.strip()
          print(f"{i+1}-{j}")

enter image description here
Output by python is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kanha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\main1.py", line 17, in <module>
    file = open('files/todos.txt','r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/todos.txt'

I want to open my file which is in different directory..

you could use the complete path of your file:
'C:\Users\kanha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\files\todos.txt' instead of using 'files/todos.txt'
Another option would be to use '..\files\todos.txt' as relative path to your current directory.
Hope this helps!

I came across a similar problem months ago, depending on your code editors ( for example: VS code or IDLE), you have to state the complete path of the file just like @phylanx said.
In my case, Visual Studio code needed the complete path of the file whereas IDLE did not.
(My grammar may suck because English is not my first language, so apologies for that.)
Hope this helps!
